# What's the iPhones Screen Dimensions for Coding?

Tags: iphone

How many pixels is the available area for an image view in iPhone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need to, you can have access to the full 480x320 screen with something like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
self.navigationController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

You will also find useful this info I [found](http://forums.ilounge.com/archive/index.php/t-224401.html) in this post:

[Status bar](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/art/ui_statusbartypes.jpg): 20 pixels
[Nav bar](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/art/ui_navbarnonavigation.jpg): 44 pixels
[Tab bar](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/art/ui_selecteditemmodeswitcher.jpg): 49 pixels
[Toolbar](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/art/ui_taskstyletoolbar.jpg): 44 pixels

Hope it helps.

Comment: Here's another method to hide the status bar, this one will actually hide it while the application is loading (and displaying your loading screen)

http://www.satosoft.com/?p=19

Comment: Don't completely rely on these numbers. For instance the status bar can be 40px height if there's incoming phone call, the nav bar and toolbar can be smaller in landscape mode, and not to mention the 1024x768 iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [visual representation](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html) of the dimensions of the specific elements mentioned by Pablo.

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend:
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=iphone+screen+resolution&btnG=Google+Search&aq=0&oq=iphone+screen+res

(short answer: 480 x 320)

Comment: Google is our friend, but StackOverflow is our best friend. ;)